# Carrierwave upload hits Errno::EEXIST - file exists error

Tags: carrierwave, osx-snow-leopard, capistrano3

Have installed a rails3.2.18 application on two machines: a Ubuntu 14.04 and osx 10.6 for testing purposes.

Submitting a file for upload on the OS X box (these files are intentionally big) with carrierwave returns `Errno::EEXIST in [...] controller` specifying:

```
File exists - /Users/user/app/releases/20141018152115/public/uploads
```

This error is not occurring on Ubuntu installation.  `public/uploads` exists because it needs to be a symlink to `shared/public/uploads` for persistence requirements. The capistrano3 deploy command

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
```

sets the symlink up. For good measure I ran deploys on both machines sequentially to isolate any app issues.

So this again appears to be an OSX issue.  One assumption is that the given stage file is somehow misconfigured for OSX, although the (only) user with admin rights is appropriately specified:

```
set :deploy_to, '/Users/osxuser/app'
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_user, 'osxuser'
```

Another assumption is related to the migration from Capistrano2 to Capistrano3, as this osX server did not have such issues prior to the upgrade.

How can the 'file exists' error be eliminated?

**Update**

```
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:244:in `mkdir'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:244:in `fu_mkdir'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
/Users/osxuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:290:in `mkdir!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:209:in `copy_to'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:131:in `block in cache!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:17:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:327:in `cache'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:179:in `production_file='
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:38:in `production_file='
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:216:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:215:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/bozzadocuments_controller.rb:62:in `block in update'
```

the stack trace appears to be wanting to mkdir `carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:290:in mkdir!`

the carrierwave uploader is specified as follows

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.quote.cart_id}_#{model.quote.cart.created_at}_/#{model.quote_id}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Comment: Can you work out exactly what the gem is trying to do when it's throwing the error? i.e. is it trying to write to `/uploads`, or failing to navigate the symlink e.g. due to permissions, or something else? If you can't see from stack traces etc. then you could use dtruss to debug this as a last resort. Might you need to tell it `/uploads/` with a trailing slash to mean "write to this directory" rather than "write to this specific file path"?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the stack trace. It appears to be having a problem with the pre-existing symlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pitfall when creating an OS-X 'alias' instead of a symlink.

(Not in the actual gems resp. any specific version – I experienced the same today with rails 5.0.0.1, ruby 3.2.1 and carrierwave 0.11.2.)

It turned out that I had accidently created not a *symlink* but an *alias* using the OS X Finder (which technically is **not** a symlink). When carrierwave then tries to create the folder structure `FileUtils.mkir_p` raises an error on trying to (re)create the (existing) alias as a directory.

`rm ./app/releases/20141018152115/public/uploads
ln -s ./app/shared/public/uploads ./app/releases/$timestamp/public/uploads`

should do the trick.

[EDIT: Clarified the actual root cause is not in ruby, rails or the gems in use]

Comment: Oh good on you to respond notwithstanding the age of the question. ++

Comment: It's kind of a timeless question as it is not related to the actual versions (or even the actual gem carrierwave) but sort of a common pitfall on OSX, so I thought this might still be helpful for you or future visitors :)

Comment: The fact that it is not version related ought to be in the answer to improve it.